# php strtotime daily countdown to a specific time

Tags: php

I've been trying to create a timer that will countdown daily to 2PM everyday.  After 2PM it should display the amount of hours until 2PM the following day. I've been able to use the following code for future dates, just not "today" everyday.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$iTimeTo = strtotime('today 14:00)';  
$iDiffTime = $iTimeTo - time();  
printf("Remaining: %s\n", date('H:i', $iDiffTime));
```

The output doesn't display the correct amount of hours remaining.

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question?

Comment: Why `$iTimeTo`? Why not `$time_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strtotime('today 14:00');
```

becomes the past after 2pm, so you'll start getting nonsensical results between 2pm and midnight.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$today = strtotime('today 14:00');
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow 14:00');
$now = time();
$timeLeft = ($now > $today ? $tomorrow : $today) - $now;
printf("Remaining: %s\n", gmdate("H:i:s", $timeLeft));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$iTimeTo = strtotime('today 14:00)';
```

should be:

```
$iTimeTo = strtotime('today 14:00');
```

Other than that, I see no reason why it wouldn't work, I've tested it and it gives me "Remaining: 20:59".

Comment: Remaining should be 2 hours ? 2PM EST (Currently 12:00 EST at the time of this posting)

Comment: I'm GMT based and on the test environment I couldn't force set the local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gmdate()` function to format the remaining "seconds" into Hours:MinuteS:Seconds like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$iTimeTo = strtotime('today 14:00');  
$iDiffTime = $iTimeTo - time();  
printf("Remaining: %s\n", gmdate("H:i:s", $iDiffTime));
```

Outputs:

```
Remaining: 01:59:55
```

Comment: @Sébastien - yes I see that now.. Thx.